# How can you upload multiple pictures when you post on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, images

I see on my iPhone there are people who post and you see one picture and you can swipe to the left and other pictures come up as well. I can't see anywhere to post multiple pictures when you post so I am trying to figure out how these people do that.

Does anyone know how to post multiple pictures when you post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you actually post on facebook, you can only upload one photo or video.

What your friends have done is uploaded a bunch of photos in an album, and after the upload was successful, facebook asked them to post about the photos that just uploaded - only in this post there can be more than one photo, not in your ordinary post.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is to share an album. From your Facebook stream page, click *Add photo/video*, and select *Create photo album*.

This will let you upload any number of photos, and share them on your stream.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for a desktop computer:

1. Create a new post with the text you want
2. Add a picture to the post either by dragging and dropping a photo onto the post or insert a picture with the Photo/Video button
3. Click the Post button
4. Locate your post on the wall and hit the ... button and choose Edit post
5. Click the Photo/Video button once more and then add all the photos and videos you want

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, easily resolved. Put the pictures in a folder on the Facebook page, then make a link. Very easily done.